# Unexplainable crash when accessing non-optional property in singleton

Tags: ios, swift

My architecture is as follows:

We create a singleton *BusinessLogic* instance which contains several *categories*, represented by classes defined in extensions.

```
class BusinessLogic {
  static let shared = BusinessLogic()

  private(set) var foo: FooCategory = FooCategory()
}
```

In a different file we define the *category*.

```
extension BusinessLogic {
  class FooCategory {
    var hasNewItems: Bool = false
  }
}
```

In reality the class is much bigger, but these are the relevant parts.

From my view controllers I access the properties like

```
BusinessLogic.shared.foo.hasNewItems
```

This is done throughout the app, and usually works without problems. In this example though, we access the hasNewItems property on viewDidLoad of our UITabBarController, which sometimes leads to crashes. This is unexplainable to me.

Does anyone have an idea what might lead to the crash? We access the BusinessLogic class even on appStart inside the AppDelegate, where everything works fine.

Comment: "which sometimes leads to crashes" what does the crash says?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include that.
Crashlytics just tells me the following:
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread. EXC_BREAKPOINT 0x000000010276df48.

The line highlighted is the one which accesses the hasNewItems property.

Comment: try checking each one of the four insrances during debug, one of them might be nil, BusinessLogic or shared or foo or hasNewItems. Maybe one of them is actually nil.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to reproduce it. Will report back.

Comment: It seems like one property was in fact nil. I don't think posting the whole solution is of any use for you, since it's very specific to my app. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like one property was in fact nil (as @Rishabh suggested). I don't think posting the whole solution is of any use for you, since it's very specific to my app.